# browser image scaling not rendering subpixels

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-10, image-scaling

aliasing is expected when increasing the size of an image however on most of the browsers I have tested I get aliasing when scaling the image size down...

it's almost as if the browsers downsample the images instead of properly re-sizing them...

http://picpaste.com/JOxEhY9n.png
this picture has no aliasing issues at full size, but this is what happens when reducing the size...

I know the browser can do better because fonts at the same size range show up fine.

It's as if the browser has a rendering resolution limit on pictures that doesn't apply to fonts...

is there any way to fix this?